# Is it safe to call LoadLibrary from main()?

Tags: windows, dll, native

I've read that it isn't safe to call `LoadLibrary()` from DllMain [[source]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But is it safe to call from the entry-point of a console application, `main()`? I can't seem to find any information on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.  If you couldn't call `LoadLibrary` from `main` you couldn't call it from anywhere in a console process, which would be daft.

`DllMain` is special because the "loader lock" is held during the call and it is called (for statically linked DLLs) before the process is fully initialized.

Answer (score 1):

From your own link:

> The entry-point function should perform only simple initialization or termination tasks. 
>   It must not call the LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx function (or a function that calls these functions), 
>   because **this may create dependency loops in the DLL load order**.

As a console application is not a part of the DLL loading chain, it is safe